# Multiple web deploys for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an application that is installed at several different client's servers.  They each have different web.config files and different virtual folders.  At the moment I am compiling, manually copying over, setting up IIS, changing web.config and adding virtual folders for each install and also again when updating.

I simply don't know how to deploy using something like Web Deploy or Deployment Package that will let me create different config files or how to manage virtual folders (I would assume I would simply deploy empty folders and would still have to do this part manually).  I can handle setting up IIS and virtual folders from the start but I want each client to be able to download new versions and install them without my input (as some Clients are funny about remote access).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup build configurations for each environment. Typically, you get Debug and Release out of the box. I like to replace those with Development, Staging, and Production configurations, which allows a different web.config per environment.

Of course, when publishing, you still have to make sure you select the correct configuration.

Comment: Are you saying create a build configuration for each Client?

Comment: To cover the virtual folders is there a way to exclude folders in the Publish and Precompile?

Comment: Also the Publish method creates a package which includes a file called 'SetParameters'.  I can change this for each web.config or keep copies to be distributed which would work well as I then only need to use one build.  However it doesn't include application settings in this file, any idea how to include them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of Web Deploy and other schemes because web-servers, unlike desktops, all tend to have a unique configuration.

In my case, all of our web applications are deployed with custom-written VBScripts (much more pleasant than Batch files and without needing to relearn PowerShell). VBScript (with its default COM object library) provides a compelling platform for writing deployment scripts. And if you can't stand the syntax you can use JScript using the same tools. Bonus: Visual Studio still provides Windows scripting IntelliSense despite it not being an advertised feature).

My most recent deployment script is simple: it's a VBScript (invoked by VS's Post-build command-line) that uses 7-Zip to pack up the web application's files, then generates an `ftp.exe` batch file (then runs ftp.exe itself) that uploads the files to the server, it also generates an uploads a file called "Unpack.cmd" which calls 7-Zip to extract the files into the right place. The only manual step is executing Unpack.cmd on the server, but that can be done with Remote PowerShell, for example.

Why do you need to customise your IIS configuration separately from the application? Can't you put everything in your `web.config` file under `<system.webServer>`?

Comment: The web application is an extension of an existing desktop application which has folders storing images/documents that the desktop application references.  As we have several clients they all have different folder and database locations hence the need for virtual folders and creating seperate config files.

Comment: We solved that problem by storing clients/subscriber's files in a virtual filesystem stored in their database back-end, which meant that no data was actually stored under the application, which simplifies things like load-balancing (because it means any front-end web server can be used to service a request).

Comment: That's what I would do normally but I am unable to do this as it would affect the existing desktop application they use.